# Using AAR module in Expo Bare React Native

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

I'm facing a problem about connecting my React Native apps into Omron Device (HBF-702T-AP). They also give me sample app using java language and Library using .aar extension, but I don't know all about java and now I need to translate it into javascript function so I can use it in my application. Looking forward for somebody that possible to do this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.